# Closeness of infinite union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Is the set $\bigcup_{x \geq 0} \left\{\frac{1}{x+1} \right\} $ closed?

For all $x \geq 0$, the set $\left\{\frac{1}{x+1}\right\}$ is a single point, therefore it is closed.

But I am not sure about the infinite union.

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ means $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x>0\}$, then this set is equal to $(0,1)$.

If $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ means $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\ge0\}$, then this set is equal to $(0,1]$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wanted to mean ${x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0}$. I will clarify that.

Comment: The infinite union of closed sets need not be closed, and every non-closed set in a space where points $\{x\}$ are closed illustrates this. In particular, your set is $(0,1]$ which is not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set (call it `A`) is not closed, because $\{0\} \in \text{cl}(A) \wedge \{0\} \not\in A$. In general, the infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed.

Remember, every set is a union of closed sets (the one-point sets that contain each of its points; $A = \cup_{p \in A} \{p\}$), so if infinite unions of closed sets were necessarily closed, then all sets would be closed.